# Download file from byte[](stored in hidden field) without calling controller at client side only

Tags: c#, file, model-view-controller, download, client-side

In my MVC c# application I am using byte[] to store file data. now while downloading file, I am having it in hidden field. So want to create and download file from here only. Don't want to call controller or any server side call. Is this possible? How? I am having file contentType and file name as well in hidden field.